# Why do my Visual Studio solution executables need to run as Administrator?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, uac, elevated-privileges

I used Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 for a while and never had this problem, but with the current VS solution whenever I run the executable created from any Fortran project (both debug and release) I get the message

> This task requires this application to have elevated permissions.

and I'm asked to restart Visual Studio as Administrator.

[image]

I don't want this, I want to create executables that run not as administrator unless right-clicked => run as administrator. That has always been the case for all my solutions except this one and I cannot figure out what I did different.

How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

In your project's linker properties there is the manifest file group of options.
Inspect the value of

> UAK Execution Level

Probably it is set as

> requireAdministrator

You should change it to

> asInvoker